# Remove certain links from Meta

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How do I remove `Log in` or `Log out` and `Wordpress.org` from my META part of my wordpress blog. I use twenty eleven, if that is relevant. I've tried editing sidebar.php but seems nothing is being changed, I mean this part :

[image]

```
<aside id="meta" class="widget">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php wp_register(); ?>
                        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                        <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
```

Tried removing `<?php wp_meta(); ?>` and/or `<li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for a PHP solution...

Put this at the top of `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
function _wpMeta($o){
  $links = 'Log in|Logout|WordPress.org';
  return preg_replace('#<li>.+?('.$links.').+?</li>#','',$o);
}
ob_start("_wpMeta");
?>
```

And this at the bottom:

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: works like a charm, one more thing I realize you are doing replace of all those `<li>` with content of items in $links, I think I understand what function does. What does ob_start mean/do? and ob_end_flush?

Comment: You can read more about the function at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), but basically the callback function `_wpMeta`, which is effectively doing the replacing, is being applied to any text between the `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush`.